# PHP random decimal between two decimals with step 0.5

Tags: php, random

I want to create random number between two decimal numbers with step 0.5.

Examples: 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, ...

Use PHP To Generate Random Decimal Beteween Two Decimals

So far I can generate numbers between 0 and 5 with one decimal comma.

How to integrate step 0.5?

```
$min = 0;
$max = 5;
$number = mt_rand ($min * 10, $max * 10) / 10;
```

Comment: why not just `mt_rand($min+$step, $max-$step) + $step`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. do you mean pick randomly the numbers between min and max with step 0.5? ie one of the numbers of your list?

Comment: @MarcB if the step is 0.5 output will be `x.5`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$min = 0;
$max = 5;
echo $number = mt_rand($min * 2, $max * 2) / 2;
```

Comment: @Dagon What do you mean with `math luke` ? i don't get it

Comment: @Rizier123: Not a Star Wars fan eh?

Comment: @AbraCadaver nope, sry, never watched star wars, What does it mean?

Comment: please return all your S.O rep; but you can have it back after watching the film

Comment: this answer can give a value lower than min

Comment: @1010 And How? Then min would be 0, 1 and the half of that is 0, 0.5 ?!

Comment: @Rizier123 if min is not 0 it could return any number between min/2 and max

Comment: @1010 Min is 0! And i took the *2 away because this is so specific and 0*2 doesn't makes much sense if he changes it he can add *2 or he can add it also with 0 but 0*2 doesn't makes much

Comment: OP says he wants "to create random number between two decimal numbers". min is 0 only in the example.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way:

```
function decimalRand($iMin, $iMax, $fSteps = 0.5)
{
    $a = range($iMin, $iMax, $fSteps);

    return $a[mt_rand(0, count($a)-1)];
}
```

Comment: This, modified a little, would work well to chose anything randomly from the array of values of any type. For which there is dedicated [`array_rand` PHP function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php).

Answer (score 1):

More intuitive, less unnecessary actions:

```php
$min = 0;
$max = 5;
$step = 0.5;
// Simple for the case above.
echo $number = mt_rand($min * 2, $max * 2) * $step;
```

More general, a bit sophisticated case

```php
echo $number = mt_rand(floor($min / $step), floor($max / $step)) * $step;
```

[`mt_rand` offical docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) just in case.

Comment: Nobody uses mt_rand in 2019. Your method will obviously fail for the 0.

Comment: 1) Nobody? Did you check everybody? :) 2) http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ copy and paste the code. All works perfectly.